# indirect method for least-squares with inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-solver, sparse-matrix, least-squares

I aim to find $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that

$\min_x |D \cdot F \cdot x|^2$

subject to $x_i =  X_i$ and $x_j \geq X_j$ ,

$i \in I, j \in J$ and I and J partition ${1\cdots N}$ into two sets.

it is easy to do $D \cdot F \cdot x$ because D is diagonal and F is the discrete Fourier transform. But actually storing and computing on F is not practical.

MATLAB's lsqlin works for small cases. It looks like it uses a direct method, qpsub, if the problem has a mix of equality and inequality constraints.

Are there any solvers or quick implementations you could refer me to?

Answer (score 1):

Iterative methods for bound-constrained least squares problems exist; one example I found pretty quickly was [On Iterative Algorithms for Linear Least Squares Problems With Bound Constraints](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.36.9511) by Bierlaire, Toint, and Tuyttens.

You should still be able to use MATLAB's `lsqlin` by supplying some options to the function. To use an iterative algorithm, prior to calling `lsqlin`, set the options struct using

```
options = optimoptions(@lsqlin, 'Algorithm', 'trust-region-reflective', ...
                       'JacobMult', YourMatrixFreeObjectiveFunction)
% Your lsqlin call should look something like...
x = lsqlin(C,d,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,x0,options)
```

Consult the `lsqlin` [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) for more details.

You'll need to alter your problem slightly in order to use the trust region algorithm; the trust region reflective algorithm does not allow any equalities, so you'll have to simply set $x_{i} = X_{i}$ for $i \in I$ within your objective function, and only solve for $x_{j}$ such that $j \in J$.